# Keeping two days of Yom Tov in Israel

Tags: eretz-yisrael, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz

What are the sources for a person from chutz la'aretz (the diaspora) to keep two days of Yom Tov when visiting Israel?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your question! ....Why do you think that a visitor to Eretz Yisrael *shouldn't* keep two days? [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/46168/edit)ing that into your question would improve it, and help other people in finding an answer. Also, you might want to choose a more descriptive name for yourself, unless your favorite number is 129507 ;). Hope to see you around the site!

Comment: It doesn't seem like this question is a duplicate. The sources are mainly based on the beginning of the perek in Pesachim called "Makom shenahagu" (lit. a place where they had a custom). The halachos there in the rishonim are brought down in Tur/Shulchan Aruch in siman 468 as well as 496. A person is bound by the customs of the city in which he lives untill he becomes an established member of a different city, therefore, a person whose plans are to remain in the city in which he lives on a permanent basis but he is visiting a different city must keep the stringencies of his hometown.

Comment: The exact definition of "an established member of a different city" is the main point of disagreement as well as the most important point for most people asking this question. The Aruch Hashulchan says planning to live in the new place for a full year is enough. Rav Shlomo Zalman and the Chazon Ish are quoted in the beginning of Yom Tov Sheini K'hilchaso as saying that a concrete decision to move (to Eretz Yisra'el, maybe the reverse would not work) is enough. The Piskei Teshuvos brings down the main shitos. Most people are not quite so lenient.